# Reduce App Size in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a `xib` with one cell contains `UIImageView`. imageview has leading, trailing, top, bottom constraints. `xib` is of 4kb and file size is 4kb. I created one more class with same contraints and object programatically. That class have size of 8kb.

I need to know whether programatically creating views will take less space or with `xib` will take less space and please let me know the ways to reduce app size.

Comment: Don't put too much image inApp, just download and cache them if you needed them. .xib file is light weight, you don't have to worry about them..

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know whether programmatically creating views will take less
>   space or with xib will take less space

The views which your create using interface are automatically converted to code including constraints. So it doesn't matter on how you create your views as per the size is concerned, But if you consider usability, readability and maintenance of code interface builder is of much help.

> ways to reduce app size

Apple has given its tips on how application size can be optimized. You can check it [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to reduce app size, which is removing unused code. Here is a tool to detect unused code: WBBlades https://github.com/wuba/WBBlades. It can help you find unused classes in Objc & Swift, so you can safely remove them to reduce app size.